# How to calculate pedigree function in diabetes prediction?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I am developing a model for diabetes prediction using [this](https://www.kaggle.com/uciml/pima-indians-diabetes-database) dataset using **Logistic Regression**.

I have completed the model and my input variables are -

Pregnancies, Glucose, blood pressure, BMI, DiabetesPedigreeFunction etc.

The model gives an accuracy of **78%** which is quite good for me.

Now when I predict new values which are not in the dataset I have all the required inputs except **Pedigree function**.

I searched for it and I understand what it is but how can I calculate that?

Comment: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2245318/
Hi, this work iclude this function, and it will help you :)

Answer (score 1):

I had much better results with the decision forest. The diabetes pedigree function requires good diabetes diagnostic history of the persons relatives. Based on [this](https://machinelearningmastery.com/case-study-predicting-the-onset-of-diabetes-within-five-years-part-1-of-3/), it might be neglectable.